# Is there a way to pass a callback function over a complex object from parent to child view in Angular?

Tags: angular

So, I'm trying to factorize tables on an **Angular** project. Having too many tables that look the same, except for the number of columns, information to show and options... I thought I could make a child component to attach to every "page" where I use a table. Everything works fine, but I have a problem passing callback functions to the child component.

I'm passing all the information for the table to autogenerated in an array of an object, plus all the neccesary callback to view, edit or delete registers from the table. Callback functions don't seem to work tho.

PD: buttons is an array of objects who generate the "options" column of a table.

The information I'm passing from Parent to Child:

```
 buttons = [
    {
      popOver: 'Ver',
      classButton: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
      classIconButton: 'oi oi-eye',
      routerLink: null,
      click: () => {
        console.log('d');
      },
    },
    {
      popOver: 'Editar',
      classButton: 'btn btn-warning btn-sm',
      classIconButton: 'oi oi-pencil',
      routerLink: null,
      click: this.openmodal,
    },
    {
      popOver: 'Eliminar',
      classButton: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
      classIconButton: 'oi oi-trash',
      routerLink: null,
      click: null,
    }   ];
```

In the child, I'm showing it like this:

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons" [ngbPopover]="button.popOver" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" type="button"
          [routerLink]="button.routerLink" (click)="button.click" [ngClass]="button.classButton">
          <span [ngClass]="button.classIconButton"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the parenthesis ?

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons"
    [ngbPopover]="button.popOver"
    triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
    type="button"
    [routerLink]="button.routerLink"
    (click)="button.click()"
    [ngClass]="button.classButton">
        <span [ngClass]="button.classIconButton"></span>
</button>
```